# Why can std::copy_n not copy continuously between each call

Tags: c++11, iterator, copy

I got to find std::copy_n with a behavior like this:

```
stringstream ss;
ss.str("abcdefghij");
string str;
str.resize(10);
std::copy_n(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss), 5, str.begin());
cout << str << endl;
std::copy_n(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss), 5, str.begin());
cout << str << endl;
```

It seems that what I got printed is `abcde\n efghij"`.

Is this the correct behavior of iterator related operations ?

Answer (score 1):

The shown usage of `std::copy_n` with the arguments given should result in an output

```
abcde
efghi
```

To explain the above,

```
std::copy_n(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss), 5, str.begin());
```

copies 5 characters starting at `'a'` to the beginning of `str`. `str` is now `"abcde"` followed by 5 default `char` instances, i.e., null bytes (which aren't printed as the first null byte is interpreted as the end sentinel of the string). The null bytes stem from `str.resize(10)`. After this call, `ss` points to the position of `'e'` in `ss`. The next, identical call

```
std::copy_n(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss), 5, str.begin());
```

copies 5 characters starting at `'e'` to the beginning of `str`. `str` is now `"efghi"` followed by 5 null bytes.

If instead the output

```
abcde
abcdefghij
```

is desired, you can change the second invocation of `std::copy_n` to

```
std::copy_n(std::next(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss)), 5, str.begin() + 5);
```

which copies 5 characters starting at `'f'` to `str`, starting at `str`'s first null byte.

Comment: What makes me feel strange is that won't ```ss``` points to ```f``` after the first copy operation ? If ```ss``` points to ```'a'``` in the beginning, why doesn't it point to ```'f'``` after five read operations ? Shouldn't we get ```abcde``` and ```fghij``` after two ```copy``` operations ?

Comment: I agree that this behavior is not absolutely obvious. But this way, `std::copy_n` does only what it absolutely needs to do with its input iterator: read `n` times from it, increment it `n - 1` times. Could be that someone wants to reuse the last copied element - when reading from a file, `n` increments (instead of `n - 1`) makes the last character unreachable.